# SAR processing in R?

Tags: r, digital-image-processing, sentinel-1, synthetic-aperture-radar

Anyone know if a package for processing SAR data in R exists? Such as doing calibration, terrain correction, classification on e.g. Sentinel 1 data?

Comment: Have you looked on CRAN?

Comment: Yes i have .....

Comment: Do you have examples of non-R programs and packages that do what you want to do? For example, does GRASS or SAGA do it? Have you looked at the R connections to these?